# HTML 5 submit button not working properly

Tags: html

My assignment says to "Within the form, add a paragraph containing a submit button with the text continue." Visually, the button looks fine, but the assignment check does not confirm it. Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--
      New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
      Tutorial 7
      Case Problem 1
      CGIP Registration Form
      Author: Gunnar Mentzer
      Date:   September 26 2018
      Filename:   cg_register.html
   -->

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>CGIP Registration Form</title>
    <link href="css/cg_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/cg_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cg_forms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cg_validate.css">
    <script src="js/cg_script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="images/cg_logo.png" alt="Computer Graphics and Image Processing" id="logoimg" />
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">keynote address</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">speakers</a></li>
            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">general session</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">abstracts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">workshops</a></li>
            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">committees</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">executive session</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">advisory council</a></li>
            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">travel info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">accommodations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">banquet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">family attractions</a></li>
            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">registration</a></li>
            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">ACGIP home page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tour Sante Fe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <h1>Conference Registration Form</h1>
        <p>Required Item (*)</p>
        <form action="http://www.example/cg/register" method="post">

          
              
          
            <!-- title -->
            <div>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="titleBox" list="titleList">
                <datalist id="titleList">
            <option value="Mr."></option>
            <option value="Mrs."></option>
            <option value="Ms."></option>
            <option value="Prof."></option>
            <option value="Dr."></option>
            <option value="Assist. Prof."></option>
            <option value="Assoc. Prof."></option>
          </datalist>
            </div>

            <!-- firstName -->
            <label for="fnBox">First Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fnBox" required>

            <!-- LastName -->
            <label for="lnBox">Last Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lnBox" required>

            <!-- address -->
            <label for="addBox">Address*</label>
            <textarea name="address" id="addBox"></textarea>

            <!-- Company or University -->
            <label for="groupBox">Company or University</label>
            <input type="text" name="group" id="groupBox">

            <!-- E-mail -->
            <label for="mailBox">E-mail*</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="mailBox" required>

           <!-- Phone Number -->
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number*</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" required pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn">

            <!-- ACGIP Membership -->
            <label for="idBox">ACGIP Membership Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="acgipID" id="idBox" placeholder="acgip-nnnnnn" pattern="^acgip\-\d{6}$">

            <!-- Registration Category -->
            <label for="regList">Registration Category</label>
            <select id="regList" name="">
          <option value="member">ACGIP Member ($695)</option>
          <option value="nonmember">ACGIP Non-Member ($795)</option>
          <option value="student">ACGIP Student ($310)</option>
          <option value="poster">ACGIP Poster ($95)</option>
          <option value="guest">ACGIP Guest ($35)</option>
        </select>

             <!-- Button -->
            <p><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue"></p>
          
      </form>

    </section>

    <aside>
        <dl>
            <dt>ACGIP Member ($695)</dt>
            <dd>Eligible to attend all sessions and banquet</dd>
            <dt>Non-Member ($795)</dt>
            <dd>Eligible to attend all sessions and banquet</dd>
            <dt>Student ($310)</dt>
            <dd>Eligible to attend all sessions. <a href="#">Proof</a> of student status required</dd>
            <dt>Poster ($95)</dt>
            <dd>Eligible to attend display hall and vendor stations</dd>
            <dt>Guest ($35)</dt>
            <dd>Eligible to attend banquet only</dd>
        </dl>
    </aside>

    <footer>
        Association of Computer Graphics and Image Processing
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you might want to add a little more code? or is this all you wrote? the whole html would be more helpful in order to see whats up.

Comment: I can upload more, its just all its asking is for a button that says continue in the form section, which is what I posted, so idk what could be wrong.

Comment: The "assignment checker" is broken. What you have written is fine and valid HTML, and fulfills the assignment to a T. Complain to the teacher that there is more than one way to complete the assignment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey haha i actually did and i sent my code and she didnt seem to have an answer, the button works and looks fine, and the solution posted here all work as well, but none actually work with the checker

Answer (score 0):

i think it meant this way bud.

```
<form>
  <p> this is a paragraph </p>
  <button type='submit'>Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I just added the type because its in his question. 
 Always specify the type attribute for the <button> element. Different browsers may use different default types for the <button> element. thats from w3 this link
 https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: I don't think the assignment wants a paragraph with text, thats why i was using this method 
         `<!-- Button -->
        <p><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue"></p>`

Comment: that method doesnt show any p text, it just has the button

Comment: so within the paragraph? 
mean like. `<p><button>continue</button></p>` im confused dude.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your assignment, you were almost there.

> > Within the form, add a paragraph containing a submit button with the text continue.

```
... some code 
<p><button type="submit" name="continue">Continue</button></p>

</form>
```

The button is inside a paragraph. The input you chose was not a button, just change `input` to `button` and add the text `Continue` between the button tags.